# C++ How to append a string to BYTE array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memcpy

I have following code in C++ (wrote in Visual Studio 2010).

```
void TEST(BYTE  data[], int size)
{
    wstring aData = L"Here is my string";
    //something code to append aData string to data array
    WinHttpClient client(url);
    // Send HTTP post request.
    client.SendHttpRequest(L"POST");
}
```

How can i append aData string to data BYTE array.

Comment: is `data` some form of binary blob? If so, why would you want to tack a string on the end? What's that even going to mean?

But the answer is: you can't append it, you'll need to create a new buffer into which you copy the data and then the string.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

So you get passed the BYTE[] and the size, but you don't know if the data is on the stack or heap, so you can't just use `realloc` or something to make it bigger.

One approach is to make sure the array is bigger than you need, and pass the current and max size.

Another approach would be to change the API to allow you to use `realloc` or similar to resize the array.

The only way I can think of without changing the API is to use some sort of marker in `data` to delimit used and unused space (doesn't work for binary data). e.g. 0 means unused, so you can just look for the first `0` and start appending from there.

**edit**
Perhaps I misread the intent. If you don't want to make a permanent change, you could take a local copy, append to that (and make sure you clean it up). I thought you wanted a permanent, "in place" append.

Comment: Thank for your answer. How about if i change byte array to pointer? Like this: void TEST(BYTE  * data, int size) Im calling this function from C#. Honesty i do not have more experience with C++.

Comment: You still don't know what you are pointing at and whether there is space to append to it or not. To do something like "realloc" you either need to return a new array or take make the array parameter something you can modify.

Comment: Can i create a new array and copy this array to there and convert string to array and copy to there?

Comment: @MrTung, It seems that what you really want to know is how to pass a string from c# into c++, and then return a different string from c++ to c# correctly, including memory management. You might want to change your question, including *how* you are calling a c++ function from c# at all. Is this a dll? Are you talking about C++ .net? Etc.

Comment: @StevenHansen Thank for your comment. I know how to calling a C++ function from C#. I have a byte array from C# and pass to C++ function. For some reason i want to append some text to this byte array and post to web service using WinHttpClient.

Comment: @MrTung, that is NOT how you want to pass String data.  Herein lies your problem.

Comment: @StevenHansen Sorry what does your mean? I know i can convert string to byte array and merge before pass to C++ function. But the most of important, i want to append a string to byte array in C++ code then post this data to web service. Simply, i can pass the byte array to C++ function and its working well. Now i want to merge this byte array with a string to post to web service.

Comment: @MrTung, There are *other*, and better ways to pass a String than as a byte array of unknown structure.  Additionally, instead of appending the string to the existing string, you should probably create a *new* string that contains a concatenation, and return that. Regardless, this is too long a conversation for comments. Take my advice or not, but I'd change your question personally.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <boost/locale/encoding_utf.hpp>

std::wstring utf8_to_wstring(const std::string& str)
{
    return utf_to_utf<wchar_t>(str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size());
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char test[10];
    std::string tesStr((char*)test);
    wstring temp = utf8_to_wstring(tesStr);

}
```